# Calculate code metrics on jar file

Tags: java, file, jar, metrics

I am working on Java source codes that are in JAR format.
I've download so many code metrics tools but they don't work with JAR files, they only work with Java files.

Would you suggest a code metrics analyzer for JAR files?

Comment: extracting from jar via jar xvf jarfile.jar is not a good option ?

Comment: Extract files from Jar and than use Metric evaluation tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com) can analyse jar,war,ear,maven,eclipse,netbeans and Intellij projects, And provides more than 82 metrics and also a CQL (like SQL for database) to request your code.

Comment: thanks for your tip. i download javadepend , and opened select project files to analyze , i drag and drop whole eclipse folder to this windows but it shows an errors what can i do to analyze whole eclipse source code ???

Comment: you can use "Add Eclipse Workspace" to add your eclips workspace , or use Browse Button to add only one eclipse project with extension .project, JavaDepend will retreive all informations from workspace file about the path of your source code, dependencies,... And feel free to contact us at support@javadepend.com to help you acheiving the analysis of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

I extract jar file and use [PREST](https://code.google.com/p/prest/) , it's really useful and easy to use.